# Jquery parent sibling reset css

Tags: jquery, css, parent, reset, siblings

I wanted to create a list of buttons(3)
Which act as follows
1) Change background and color on mouse enter and Reset to basic style on mouse leave.
2) Change Background and color on Click.
3) act as radio buttons.(i.e. When i select 1 button Other buttons must return to their basic style).

```
<ul>
     <li>
          <span class="Change_button">Button1</span>
     </li>
     <li>
          <span class="Change_button">Button2</span>
     </li>
     <li>
          <span class="Change_button">Button3</span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

by using the following code i am able to accomplish my first two needs

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".Change_button").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css({background:"url('button_hover.jpg') repeat scroll 0 0 transparent", color:"#FFFFFF"});
});
$(".Change_button").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css({background:"#C5C5C5 url('apply.jpg') center top repeat-x", color:"#625C54"
 });
}); 
$(".Change_button").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent("li > span").css({background:"#C5C5C5 url('apply.jpg') center top repeat-x", color:"#625C54"});
    $(this).css({background:"url('button_hover.jpg') repeat scroll 0 0 transparent", color:"#FFFFFF"});
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css({background:"url('button_hover.jpg') repeat scroll 0 0 transparent", color:"#FFFFFF"});
    }); 
});
});
```

But,i am unable to reset the style(default style) of the remaining buttons when we click on one of the button

```
    **CSS**
li {
display: inline;
font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
list-style: none outside none;
}
span {
background:#C5C5C5 url('apply.jpg') center top repeat-x;
border: 1px solid #BABABA;
color: #625C54;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 14px;
min-width: 60px;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

I searched problems related this issue, but, i couldn't find any. My bad,If there are any.

Comment: Please show the **actual code**.

Comment: I provided every thing

HTML
CSS
and Jquery

Comment: `$("class")` => `$(".class")`

Comment: Still doesn't look like the actual code...

Comment: There you go.. actual code..

Comment: The code is still unclear. The .click() function and the .mouseleave() function does the same stuff.

Comment: yeah.. i intentionally placed that .mouseleave method in .click function(if i did not place the first .mouseleave method changes back the style that .click function changed) . When the button click event occurred I want the same style(changed style in .click function) even after the my mouse that span element. .mouseleave method in .click function overrides the previous .mouseleave method
so that the element style does not change on the mouse leave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JJsAx/2/)

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul>
     <li>
          <span class="Change_button">Button1</span>
     </li>
     <li>
          <span class="Change_button">Button2</span>
     </li>
     <li>
          <span class="Change_button">Button3</span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
display: inline;
font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
list-style: none outside none;
}
span{
border: 1px solid #BABABA;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-right: 14px;
min-width: 60px;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: auto;
border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
cursor:pointer;
}
span.Change_button{
    color: #625C54;
}
span.Change_button:hover{
    background:"#C5C5C5;
    color: red;
}
span.toggle{
    color: blue;
}
span.toggle:hover{
    color: lightgreen;
}
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('.Change_button').click(function(){
    $('.toggle').addClass('Change_button').removeClass('toggle');
    $(this).removeClass('Change_button').addClass('toggle');
});
```

**Explanation:**

When the user clicks on the button, it adds a 'toggle' class and removes the 'change_button' class. Hence the button is toggled and another style applies which you can manage with css. The other buttons retain their 'change_button' class & styles.

All effects are being done in CSS.

Comment: I think i overthink for this. For the above problem this is right solution.. but i have 7 sets for those 3 buttons.. i have same class for all those button.. NO problem i can take it from here.. anyhow thank you for the answer

Comment: Add different classes for differents sets. An html element can have multiple classes as you already know :)

Comment: is there any way select only the present set without using multople classes

Comment: If your present set is unique, then use IDs. or a custom HTML attribute(however those ain't compatible with css selectors).

Answer (score 0):

$(this).parent().parent("li > span").css(default style);
$(this).parent().siblings().css(default style);
this has too be like this if your Selectors select the right Element (Dom)
You have to make  lIKE THIS`$(this).parent().parent("li > span").css({
"background-color": "#C5C5C5",
"background-image": "URL(../IMAGES/....)",
"background-repeat": "repeat-x"
});`